# Virtual brackets in Python

Tags: python, linux

(Warning: Potential flame-war starter. This is however not my goal, the point here is not to discuss the design choices of Python, but to know how to make the best out of it).

Is there a program, script, method (Unix-based, ideally), to display "virtual" brackets around blocs of code in Python, and to keep them where they are so that the code can still be executed even if indenting is broken ?

I realize that Python only uses indentation to define blocks of code, and that the final program may not contain brackets.

However, I find it very annoying that your program can stop functioning just because of an unfortunate and undetected carriage-return.

So, ideally I would be looking for a plugin in a text editor (kate, gedit...) that would:

- Display virtual brackets around blocks of code in my Python program
- Keep them in place
- Generate dynamically the "correct" Python code with the indentation corresponding to where the brackets belong.

(no flame-war, please !)

Comment: 1. Type the brackets into your editor. Use correct indentation inside brackets. 2. Remove the brackets automatically before giving the source to Python. You could write the tool for this in Python itself.

Comment: Obligatory comment: try `from __future__ import braces`

Comment: Python already supports block delimiters: http://www.python.org/doc/humor/#python-block-delimited-notation-parsing-explained

Comment: Have you found an undetected carriage return to be a real issue in real code, or is this mainly hypothetical? One of the arguments usually raised in favour of the meaningful indentation is that a bug the other way around (indentation not matching braces in a brace language -> frustration) is more common/more likely. Have you found the opposite?

Comment: When you write Python in a text editor with the slightest support for it, you don't have to ever do indentation yourself. Bocks always start at a `:` so consider this your `{` and the backspace key you hit at the end of a block is the `}`

Comment: Wait, how can a *carriage-return* of all things mess up Python's indenting? If you don't have code in that line, it doesn't do anything..

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: I can't agree with you on that one. I am a seasoned programmer (20+ years) and have used many languages. For the past four years I have almost exclusively used python, and I *still* find them annoying. I use emacs, so for the most part they are a non-issue, but they still rear their ugly head once in a while. Python is an awesome language, but for the life of me I can't see why anyone thinks whitespace for block definitions are a good idea. Obviously people do, but I don't understand it. <shrug>

Comment: @BryanOakley It's not a feature I like about python, it's just become transparent. curly braces rear their ugly head once in a while, too, when an un-closed block in an `.h` causes a compiler error in another file... :)

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: good point. Maybe the spaces thing is more frustrating because they are invisible. If I have a missing bracket it's easy to spot. Having one line with a tab instead of spaces or visa versa is impossible to spot without help. That tends to "up" the frustration quotient.

Answer (score 1):

I used an editor that does code rollups and understood Python syntax, then I looked for rollups that are in unexpected locations.  I don't remember if Kate does that.  It's not obvious that there is an issue, but it makes it easier when you are looking for an issue.